# How to use scroll magic to scroll snap and be full screen?

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, fullpage.js, scrollmagic, scroll-snap-points

I want to create a section similar to the “App timers” section on this page(it's towards the bottom): https://www.android.com/versions/pie-9-0/. I  can only have one section like this on my page with the rest being normal scroll.

I see that they use scrollmagic but I can’t seem to find examples similar to this in their documentation or that any one has done. I considered using fullpage.js, but I can’t seem to make it work with only one section activated like that in the middle.

Any suggestions?